# Sending a web page by email programmatically. Image URLs not resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am writing a SharePoint timer job, which needs to pull the content of a web page, and send that HTML as an email.

I am using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects to pull the content.

The emailing functionality works fine except for one problem.

The web page which serves up the content of my email contains images.

When the html of the page is sent as an email, the image URLs inside the HTML code are all relative URLs, they are not resolved as an absolute URL.

How do i resolve the image URLs to their absolute paths inside the web page content?

Is there any straight forward way to do this? I don't want to run a Regex over the html code to replace all relative URLs with absolute URLS.

Comment: you could just run a rege...oh.

Comment: Is one of the provided answers correct? If so, could you mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: I used Html AgilityPack.. Please see my answer below.. I Have marked it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this cool Codeplex tool called HtmlAgilityPack. 
http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Using this API, we can parse Html like we can parse XML documents. We can also query and search nodes using XPath.

I used the following code snippet to fix the Image URLs

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlMessage);

//This selects all the Image Nodes
            HtmlNodeCollection hrefNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

            foreach (HtmlNode node in hrefNodes)
            {
                string imgUrl = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
                node.Attributes["src"].Value = webAppUrl + imgUrl;
            }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

            htmlDoc.OptionOutputAsXml = false;
            htmlDoc.Save(sw);
            htmlMessage = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.4) element to the head of the html document you retrieve. As `href` attribute you should use the url of the page you are retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem a few times, and I dont think there is any magic wand method out there to do it all for you. HTMLAgilityPack does a good job for aggregating the content you need, but you will have to decipher it yourself. For example; getting the list of HtmlNodes that contain "//img" could return any of the following items:

```
<img src="http://www.adg2435.com/pictures/pic.jpg"/> //absolute url
<img src="coolpicture.jpg"/> //relative to the page
<img src="pictures/pic.jpg"/>
<img src="./pictures/pic.jpg"/>
```

It is up to you to figure out which types of links are going to show up on the given webpage.
You also need to account for things like this: (Truncate your image url after the extension ".jpg")

```
<img src="/pictures/pic.jpg?45823593&xyz=95325235r0634945823ot49140200"/>
```

So, I find it handy to keep a few things on hand at any given time:

1. The source URL for the entire page
2. The domain for the given url (to do things like say "does the given src contain the domain?")
   This is how you would get the domain of the source link:

   Uri domainUri = new Uri(fullUrl);
   domainUrl = domainUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
3. Potentially, you may want the subdomain (i.e. "http://www.mysite.com/pictures/")

Answer (score -5):

> I don't want to run a Regex over the html code to replace all relative URLs with absolute URLS.

Too bad, because that's the only way you'll get the images to show up.  Would you rather download all the images and embed them in the email too?